# What is that blue round thing below the resistor?

Tags: resistors, identification

What is thing blue thing (pointed by red arrow) below the resistor? It comes in blue, red, silver, green, and red. Is it part of the resistor? What does the color signify?

[image]

Comment: Some context is always useful in questions like this. What does the circuit do? In what section are the resistors? Add the info into the question and someone should be able to confirm their type and explain *why* they are there.

Comment: Probably a plastic spacer for stress relief.

Comment: It's input resistor to an op amp. I thought it was some form of enhanced tolerance or temperature coefficent or  additional feature.

Comment: `It comes with blue, red, silver, green, red?` ... are you asking if it is available in different colors?

Comment: `What does it signify in the color chart?` ... which color chart?

Comment: They might possibly be ferrite beads. You can check with a magnet.

Comment: It looks like the board was laid out for a physically smaller resistor - perhaps one with a lower power rating. If so, the substitution could have forced the need for vertical mounting, which created the need for what could be a spacer. FWIW, where resistors are vertically mounted, it's usually to save space on the board; the pads would be closer together. This seems a bit wasteful of space, so seems to me like there may have been some sort of design error here.

Answer (score 15):

Looks like a simple spacer. It's bad (for reliability and stability through soldering) to have the part too close to the solder blob.

Those are precision resistors (and it looks like some kind of industrial or similar higher-than-average cost/specification product).

The beads look a lot like [test point spacers](https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_DkFVn6X):

[image]

Comment: I agree, a spacer.  High-reliability construction. For space between the body and the solder joint. This ensures the solder joint forms a good fillet & doesn't extend up to the body. Mechanical shock & vibration will be evenly spread out, to minimize cracks forming in the joint.  The color may be a code to indicate what diameter of wire its designed for.  But this in particular product, vertical mounting is not a reliable choice. Vertical mount has higher center of mass than if horizontal, and, if dissipating any significant power, will lead to temperature hot spot at the top.

Comment: Big chance it’s a ferrite bead

Comment: @RemyHx Not sure what possible use a ferrite bead would be on a 10MΩ 1% resistor lead, but if they are magnetic then would believe it. Not everything has to make sense.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany that’s a good point. It’s a pity we don’t have more info about the board.

Comment: Normally you'd just use lead forming to hold the resistor off the board. I wonder why they used a physical spacer.